# How to fix Dockerfile permission denied to /app?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a node js project and this is the related Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14.16.0-alpine3.13

RUN addgroup app && adduser -S -G app app
RUN mkdir /app && chown app:app /app
USER app

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

As you see, I gave the relevant access to the app, but when I run `docker-compose up` on my ubuntu 18 server, I get this error:

```
Step 6/9 : RUN npm install
 ---> Running in d95487caef6b
npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /app
npm WARN unihi-backend@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN unihi-backend@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! path /app
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/app'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/app'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/app'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/app/.npm/_logs/2021-11-10T10_53_06_750Z-debug.log
The command '/bin/sh -c npm install' returned a non-zero code: 243
ERROR: Service 'api' failed to build : Build failed
```

Note: api is my app service name.

Also, this project with the same dockerfile is working on my local system (windows).

Comment: `RUN npm install` is run by root. Why are you bothering with a user `app`?
The error is caused because root cannot access the dir `/app` because it is owned by the user app

Comment: @LinFelix Thanks for your tip. I tried removing lines 3, 4, and 5 related to adding the "app" user, but again I got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my trial and errors, I realized that instead of this commands:

```
$ docker-compose build
$ docker-compose up -d
```

I should use `docker-compose up -d --build`
And then it works correctly.